# Math&JS: sinusoidal animation

Tags: javascript, html, math, trigonometry

given incremental values form 0 to infinite
I'd like to get back a value that increase, then decrease, then increase, then decrease...like a sine

I'm basically trying to get an animation of a ball that goes up and down, based on input values that are only linearly increasing (this value is given by scrolling the page for example to from 0px to TBD +1)

what the math function should I use?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, [JavaScript has a sine function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin):

```
var y = Math.sin( Math.PI );   // returns 0
```

`Math.sin()` takes its argument in radians.

If you want to "slow down" the oscillation, what you have to do is stretch out the input parameter: just divide what you're passing into the sine function by some constant.  For example, if `x` is your input parameter, and you want the animation to go half as fast, do this:

```
var y = Math.sin( x / 2 );
```

Also keep in mind that sine goes negative; its range is [-1,1].  So if you want to avoid the negative values, you'll have to add 1 to the output of the function:

```
var speed = 0.5;  // 2=2x speed, 0.5=half speed, etc.
var y = (Math.sin( x * speed ) + 1)/2;
// y will range from [0,1]
```

See this jsfiddle for a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/r8yRN/

Comment: thank you! I actually tried it var ballY = Math.sin( x ) * 100; where x is the with +1 increments, but for some reason the ball oscillate up and down but too fast...i forgot all about sin and geometry i dont remeber how to extend the frequency...